# Why can't I replace EventExecutorChooser in MultithreadEventExecutorGroup netty 4

Tags: netty

I was wondering why is the `EventExecutorChooser` is private member in `MultithreadEventExecutorGroup` and cannot be replaced?
It seems like Netty went to this direction... refactored the default RR thread selector to an Interface with 2 strategies.

I need to control the thread that handled the `channel`, do the load balancing myself between the `EventLoops`

A public method like `getChooser()` would be great, then I could simply override it and give my own Chooser...
The only option I can see now is to Override\implement `MultithreadEventExecutorGroup` and replace the `EventExecutorChooser`

Thanks

Comment: Please review https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/5279 if you are interested in doing this.

Answer (score 1):

They planed to expose EventExecutorChooser from MultithreadEventExecutorGroup, but haven't finished it.

Refer: [Pluggable algorithm to choose next EventLoop](https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/2788)